# Current way to use rlang and tidyeval inside functions

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

Just wondering what the current start of the art is for using tidyeval principles inside a function.

Imagine we have two `tibble`s in our environment, and we want to pass their names to a `purrr::map` call:

```
library(tidyverse)

t1 <- tribble(
  ~name,
  "foo"
  )

t2 <- t1
```

To print `t1` and `t2` via references to their names as strings, this works:

```
ls() %>% 
  map(
    ~get(.x)
    )
```

ut my attempt at more idiomatically tidyeval approaches don't

```
ls() %>% 
  map(
    ~{{.x}}
  )

ls() %>% 
  map(
    ~enquo(.x)
  )


ls() %>% 
  map(
    ~sym(.x)
  )
```

These all print the objects' names, not their contents.

How does this working using the tidyeval approach?

Comment: In this case `ls() |> mget()` is probably more direct. Not sure what trying to use `rlang` really adds to this type of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `eval()` to evaluate the symbols

```
ls() %>% 
    map(
        ~eval(sym(.x))
    )
```

Note this way only works with `sym()`. so depending on what you want to do you might have to find a way to evaluate the other captured expressions.